# Why ln -sf does not overwrite existing link to directory

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils, ln

According to documentation, command `ln -f` removes existing destination file. Does this mean that if I create a symlink, -f should remove of overwrite any existing symlink at destination?

I have a symlink, say, L, pointing to DIR1 and type `ln -sf DIR2 L`. But L still points to DIR1. Only after `rm L` this command creates a link pointing to DIR2.

With symlinks to **files** it behaves as expected.

What's wrong with links to **directories**?
(bash 4.3.48 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and Windows WSL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run:

```
ln -sf DIR2 L
```

This is creating a symlink inside `DIR1`, because symlink `L` points to directory `DIR1` and `ln` dereferences the symlink `L`, resulting in creation of `L/DIR2 -> DIR1`.

The following:

```
#rm -fr DIR1 DIR2 L
mkdir DIR1 DIR2
ln -v -s DIR1 L
ls -la L
ln -v -f -s DIR2 L
ls -la L
```

will output:

```
'L' -> 'DIR1'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 runner runner 4 Oct 21 18:13 L -> DIR1
'L/DIR2' -> 'DIR2'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 runner runner 4 Oct 21 18:13 L -> DIR1
```

To handle that, use the `--no-dereference` option as indicated in [answer in this thread on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/645842/how-to-overwrite-a-symbolic-link-of-a-directory).

Comment: where is DIR1 in first command?

Comment: hi @EugenKonkov There is no `DIR1` in `ln -sf DIR2 L` command. I do not understand.

Comment: You wrote: `When you run: ln -sf DIR2 L .This is creating a symlink inside DIR1 ...`.

Comment: And _right after_ what you posted I wrote "cause L points to DIR1 and ln dereferences it". I am sorry, which parts of the sentence is unclear to you? Then the answer follows with a practical example showcasing the issue. Then the answer follows with how to circumvent the behavior with a link that also explains the behavior. I'm sorry, I do not understand. Did you read the linked answer, maybe it will clear things up for you? I tried to edit the sentence, but I do not feel there is anything more to add. Kindly write specifically what is unclear to you.